# CSS - Height/Overflow Issues

Tags: html, css

Basically, When I am on my PC on my site it is fine everything is formatted Correctly.

But when I zoom out it makes the background html colour show (Void kinda). No idea why its doing this but some users have pointed out that tablets and specifically iphones show this just from normal browsing.

Not sure as to what kind of code I can show as an example so just checkout the site: http://toolnet.work/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use CSS **Viewport Height** unit where `1 vh` is relative to 1% of the height of the screen.

```
div#page-wrapper {min-height:100vh;}
```

or

```
<div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg dashbard-1" style="min-height: 100vh;">
```

Comment: Just to say the min-height thing going on was just test CSS. Is this what I actually need to do?

Comment: You actually need to set the `min-height` of `div#page-wrapper` to `100vh`.

Comment: Why does this way work when 100% doing the same thing doesnt?

Comment: It's because `vh` is relative to the height of the viewable part of screen, not to the height of the `div` itself.